# Is a custom exception suitable in this case?

Tags: c#, exception

I've got a piece of code which checks if an active directory domain 'exists'. I've put that in quotes because the domain:

- may not exist
- may be unreachable/offline

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{domainName}");
if(directoryEntry.Guid == null)
{
    // What exception do I throw here?
}
```

I know it's recommended to use one of the standard exceptions wherever possible. But would a custom exception be more appropriate in this case? i.e. `DomainUnreachableException` because I'm not sure if anything listed in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx#Standard) table is suitable.

Edit, just for a bit of context, the code I've shown is part of a method which sets up an object ready for further use. If certain conditions aren't met, the object is basically unusable. The conditions I have are as follows:

- SQL Server instance does not exist or is inaccessible. `ConnectionFailureException` appears to be suitable here as it's what's thrown if you try to use the object.
- Database does not exist or is inaccessible. I've used `NullReferenceException` here since the indexer returns null if it cannot access or find the database.
- Domain does not exist or is unreachable. This is the one I'm not sure of.

Comment: What would you need to do when such thing happens? If you just want to display an error message an exception with a message might be enough.

Comment: That's about it. I just need to display a message like "Domain may not exist or is unreachable/offline.". So would `System.Exception` be suitable in this case or do I need something more specific?

Comment: I think that you could create you own exception that inherits f.e. from `IOException`...

Comment: `System.Exception` is a bad choice, it means "soemthing went wrong; no comments"

Comment: @nopeflow, Can you explain why it would be an IOException?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Yes I agree, but if the OP just wants to signal that something went wrong without taking action depending on what went wrong, custom exceptions could just increase complexity when an Exception with a well defined message would suffice.

Comment: @Jake `IOException` reffers to Input/Output exception. You try to read some path / dir (input) and that is related to input/output operations in my opinion.

Comment: If you don't want creating your own exception, have a look at `throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Provided path {0} doesn't exist.", path), "path");` or alike which means "the argument 'path' has an incorrect value"

Comment: @nopeflow, Aren't `IOExceptions` typically for files/streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the object, but it's state is not valid for in the context of current operation so the [InvalidOperationException Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is appropriate according to it's description:

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.

This exception is suitable to throw if you have already decided to carry out an operation, that is a 'decided' state for a method to run.

If your method which is doing a check for `Guid == null` is supposed to describe an external resource or it's absence to make a decision, then you should not throw at all, but return a description object instead.

Comment: I'm not calling a method in this case. I'm checking a property to see if an object has been initialised correctly.

Comment: The 'method call' is the method which is doing the check in a decided state to carry out an operation. If you are to be throwing an exception, you have to have a 'decided' state, to which this situation is considered exceptional. No reason to throw otherwise. You should query for an external object's state there's no reason for an exception. It's better to obtain an object describing an external resource.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom exception makes sense when the exception-catching code is aware of this custom exception, so that it can perform some actions specific to this exception type. If no special steps should be taken after catching your custom exception or a base class exception will be caught, then there is no need to create a new type. Just pass a meaningful message to the best-fitting exception type already defined in the FCL.

Maybe you could use [ActiveDirectoryOperationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectoryoperationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: So what would be the best fitting in this case? All I need to do is inform them that the domain name might be wrong or there's a problem connecting to it.

Comment: @Jake Maybe look not at the table from the link you provided (this table lists common exceptions), but at the Inheritance Hierarchy at the top of the page. There are some in the `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` namespace.

Comment: So would `ActiveDirectoryOperationException` be a good choice since I don't need to take specific actions based on if the server doesn't exist or is down?

Comment: @Jake It's impossible to give you an accurate enough solution, but I believe it might be OK. I added this suggestion to my answer.

Comment: I've added some context to the OP. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You should throw standard exceptions when they properly describe the error that occurred. `ArgumentException`, `ArgumentNullException`, `InvalidOperationException` are very often a good choice.

In your case, you might consider throwing an `ArgumentException`. It would be a good choice if the exception was thrown only when a domain doesn't exist. However, you will also throw it when the domain exists, but is unreachable. So the `ArgumentException` will also be thrown if the domain name is correct, giving the client incorrect information.

It seems that throwing a custom exception is a good choice in this case. I don't know any standard exception that will perfectly fit your case.

And never throw `Exception` or `ApplicationException`. Clients will not be able to handle these exceptions correctly (`catch(Exception)` will catch any exception thrown in the method, not only the one you throw).

**Edit**

As Kapol noticed [ActiveDirectoryOperationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectoryoperationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might be a good choice.

When throwing specialized exceptions like this, you have to consider what the clients know about your method. If they know it's an AD operation, you can throw an AD exception. If the AD is hidden behind some abstraction, throwing it will cause a leaky abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Make one custom exception similar to `DriveNotFoundException A drive is unavailable or does not exist.` name it DomainNotFoundEcxeption inherited from Exception.